# How can I save github credentials to the server

Tags: git, github

When I do "git pull" on the Linux Ubuntu server to pull the changes from my repo, it always asks me for my GitHub account username and password. How can I save these credentials to the server forever?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git#git-credential-manager. Note that it's a bit different for mac, windows and linux.

Comment: I edited to Linux Ubuntu server, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+cache+credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git config --global user.name <username>
git config --global user.email <xxx@mail.com>
git config credential.helper store
```

Note: first time it will ask for the credentials

Comment: when execute the third command, I got: "fatal: not in a git directory"

Comment: go inside the cloned directory & run this command